# SDL minimize window

Tags: c, sdl

I am working on a game in C using SDL and I created a window with SDL_NOFRAME so I loosed   minimize & close native buttons , I added 2 buttons " _ " and " X " onclick " X " quit the game but I couldn't find a solution for Minimize " _ " any idea ?!!

Comment: http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_WM_IconifyWindow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SDL_WM_IconifyWindow` to minimize your window.

http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_WM_IconifyWindow